# clearTimeout without ID

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

Is there any way to clear `setTimeout()` if it doesn't have an explicit ID?
 The problem is I'm not allowed to change some code that already ran and set the timers without any handler.

Does JS set 'anonymous handlers' to them? Are these timers stored anywhere accessible? Can I get any of those properties (the function the timer is about to call? the time it'll be called?)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope, you can't without a reference.  You *could* try something **REALLY** hacky (don't do this! it's just an illustration of hackyness) to clear all timeouts:

```
for(var i=0; i<100000; i++) clearTimeout(i);
```

but again that's not foolproof and well beyond hacky.

Solution? Fight be able to change the source, so you can do this properly - or see if you can override the function creating the timer.

Comment: yeah, that will be the solution: fight to change the source. It'll take months :/
thanks for the hackyness :)

Comment: Wll this helped me out to debug a page where there was a timeout that redirected me away from the page... Just pasted this in my console. So this works great for debugging purposes.

Comment: Let me add an explanation of why it is better not to do so. Because you just break down third-party scripts that use setTimeout. I'm one of the developers of those scripts, and I'll find you if you break mine.

Comment: As hacky solutions go, perfect to use with client side GM scripting to neuter a specific annoying site and the only solution that worked, thanks you +1

Comment: You don't need to go through 100000 loops, you can do this with the minimum possible loops:
`var i = setTimeout(function(){}); while(i--) clearTimeout(i);`

Comment: Are you sure 100000 is enough? maybe you have to get latest id by calling `setTimeout` again ( `const last = setTimeout( _ => {}, 0)` )

Answer (score 2):

No.  The `clearTimeout` method requires that the ID returned from `setTimeout` be provided in order to remove the timeout.

Could you post some more information about your scenario?  Perhaps some code snippets?  There may be a way to work around the scenario.

Comment: I saw the clearTimeout does need indeed an ID, but I was thinking about messing around with browser variables and stuff like that.

Comment: the scenario is like this: a code I can't touch runs, creates timers witouth IDs, and, by the end of the page, a code I *can* write runs, but the timer (without ids) is already set.

Comment: @djspark is there any way you can provide a wrapper to the function which is passed to `setTimeout`?

Comment: the problem is it's already been called, therefore, the timer is set.

Comment: @djspark then i think you may be in trouble.  @Nick's solution may be the best option for you then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433926/cleartimeout-without-id/4433944#4433944

Answer (score 1):

Another possible hacky approach is to throw an error from somewhere within the timeout. For this to work, the error must (a) not be caught within a `try-catch` block; and (b) occur before the timeout has had a chance to take the actions you dislike.  Depending on the content of the timeout this may be easy, hard, or impossible.

For example, if the timeout is registered like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   if(document.URL.toUpperCase() === "..."){
      // do something that you don't like
   }
}, 60000);
```

then the only way (I think) that you can throw an error is to monkey-patch  the function `String.prototype.toUpperCase`, and check whether the calling function is the offending timeout.  You can't make this check with absolute certainty, but `(new Error).stack` will certainly come in handy...you can compare against the expected stack trace.
You can do similar things by monkey patching property getters, or perhaps by setting a specific object to `undefined`.  ES6 might give some additional possibilities.

This is decidedly hacky, and it doesn't actually clear the timeout, it only prevents it from having any outwardly observable behavior.  However, it may just do the trick!  (If performance is relevant, then be careful with your monkey-patching.)

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could make the handler check whether it should still handle the event (with a boolean variable).