# How to clear all setInterval() and setTimeOut() without knowing their ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timeout

If I don't know the return value of `setInterval()` or `setTimeOut()`, can I still use `clearInterveral(id)` or `clearTimeOut(id)` to clear them?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [clearTimeout without ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433926/cleartimeout-without-id)

Comment: Structure your code properly so that you always have the IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace original both setTimeout and setInterval like:

```
   setInterval = (function( oldsetInterval){
    var registered=[],
    f = function(a,b){
        return registered[ registered.length ] = oldsetInterval(a,b)
    };
     f.clearAll = function(){
        var r;
        while( r = registered.pop()) { 
           clearInterval( r );
        }       
    };
    return f;    
})(window.setInterval);
```

And now:

```
setInterval( function(){alert(5000)}, 5000 );
setInterval( function(){alert(10000)}, 10000 );

setInterval.clearAll();
```

Suggesting a commentary from @PointedEars you shouldn't use the same name so:

```
reportingSetInterval = as above;
reportingSetInterval( function(){alert(5000)}, 5000 );
```

and so on..

Comment: The return values of `window.setTimeout()` and `window.setInterval()` are largely undocumented (no reference, no standard, closed source), and subject to change, so your approach is not reliable. Trying to replace a host object's methods is another really bad idea.

Comment: @PointedEars: Now it's part of the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html) (which does not have to mean anything).

Comment: Really bad idea -  Why? Native function executes and returns what it should, this is only a small wrapper and is the perfect answer to this question.

Comment: If it is to be a native wrapper, you need to assign it to a declared, preferably not global variable of that name, or you would be attempting to modify a host object. See ES 5.1, 8.6.2 for why that is a bad idea.

Comment: @FelixKling HTML5 (wisely) does not specify `handle` other than its type and that it must be unique in subsequent calls.

Comment: But calling `apply` on a host object makes it a loser. Proper wrappers never do that (at least not without runtime feature test), because host objects do not need to implement `apply` (have you tested in IE?). Please delete this before anyone gets the idea that this would be viable.

Comment: It is slightly better now, but you are still overwriting a host object's method, and you are passing a host object's method needlessly, both of which are bad ideas. The former should be clear by now. The latter is a bad idea, because accessing host object's methods other than in a *CallExpression* are known to throw exceptions in IE/MSHTML, and suppose for a moment that it still works, you are calling `window.setInterval` so that `this` does not refer to the same object as `window`, which is likely to fail as well (you can't call `document.getElementById()` that way in IE/MSHTML, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a register pattern based object for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible without the original id, so storing that, maybe in an array would be a good idea