# Cancel all animations in JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I want a piece of Javascript code or some guidance on how to write one that can stop all the CSS and JS (canvas, webgl, etc.) animations in a given page.

Sometimes some animations make user's computer slow on Opera and Firefox, so i need a snippet that can help user "cancel" all css/js based animations in my web app.

Comment: why don't you detect the browser and not let it animate in opera and firefox.

Comment: the code will come from db or some api. so basically, thats what i want, how do i cancel the animations to not let it animate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this to stop the javascript:

```
 //event is the Event object
 if (event.stopPropagation) {
  event.stopPropagation ();
 }
 event.cancelBubble = true;
```

For CSS, i do not know!

Comment: i dont want to prevent any event from propagating or bubbling. i want to stop the animations, which i guess would be something related to killing all setInterval/setTimeout and maybe more.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769598/how-to-clear-all-setinterval-and-settimeout-without-knowing-their-id